# There is no increasing positive sequence $(u_{n})_{n}$ with this condition: $(u_{n}^{(1/n)})_{n}$ is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_{n})_{n}$ be an increasing positive sequence.

My **question** is about this **claim** (maybe it is false): There is no increasing positive sequence $(u_{n})_{n}$ with this condition:

$(u_{n}^{(1/n)})_{n}$ is decreasing.

Any idea is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions boil down to
$$0<u_n< u_{n+1}<u_n\cdot u_n^{1/n}.$$
There is enough leeway to build such a sequence, e.g. starting from any $u_1>1$ and recursively letting $u_{n+1}=u_n\cdot \frac{1+ u_n^{1/n}}2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Here is an idea:}\ u_1=2,\ u_2=\tfrac52,\ u_n=n,\ n\geqslant3.$$